# Validate date using call back function in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

Does anyone knows how to validate date using callback function in codeigniter in php. I am trying to make the from_date greater than the to_date. I have converted to object and comparing the dates.

I tried to using form validation and callback, but it didnt return true.       where am i wrong? Thanks in advance..
    My code is as follows..

```
 public function save()
    {

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('from_date', 'trim|required');


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('to_date','trim|required|callback_checkdate');
    }
```

My call back function is

```
 public function checkdate()
{
    if($this->input->post('from_date')!='' && $this->input->post('to_date')!='' && DateToDateObject($this->input->post('from_date')) <= DateToDateObject($this->input->post('to_date')))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call back code should contain a `set_message` method as mentioned in my answer.
Also, you dont need to check `($this->input->post('from_date')!='' && $this->input->post('to_date')!='')` as these are already required in `set_rules`.

```
public function checkdate()
{
    $from_date= new DateTime($this->input->post('from_date'));//date-formate :- YYYY-MM-DD
    $to_date= new DateTime($this->input->post('to_date'));
    if( $from_date >= $to_date)//To date must be higher i think 
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('checkdate', 'From date is bigger then to date.');                      
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

For ajax Your controller code should be like this

```
public function save()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('from_date', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('to_date','trim|required|callback_checkdate');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $errors = array();
        foreach ($this->input->post() as $key => $value)
        {
            $errors[$key] = form_error($key);
        }
        $response['errors'] = array_filter($errors); // Some might be empty
        $response['status'] = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        $response['status'] = TRUE;
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
```

In your ajax request use `datatype:'json'` 
And to show errors in ajax `success` function use

```
success:function(data) 
{
    if (data.status == true) 
    {
        console.log("form has no error");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("form has error");
        $.each(data.errors, function(key, val) {
            $('[name="'+ key +'"]', form).after(val);
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it a correct method to convert the date to object ?

Comment: You are doing this with ajax  ?

Comment: Wait i am giving you controller code also to apply :)

Comment: I am getting data through my ajax call, but the data is not getting inside the call back itself.. could nt sort it out